# Can I upgrade from 10.6 to 10.7 for free?

Tags: macos, upgrade

When I bought my new Mac at the end of July, 2011, the dealer (Microcenter, Marietta, GA) Renee told me I had 4 months to upgrade to Lion. I calendared the drop dead date at the end of November, and now discover I only had 30 days.

Is there a way to upgrade for free at this time?

Comment: Apple have great customer service.  There's always a chance they'll look favorably upon you if you go into a store and speak to them.  However, as Matti says below, you're not entitled to it now as you missed the cutoff date.

Comment: If the dealer said this then I would ask them to provide the upgrade.

Comment: I'd bring my receipt to the nearest [Apple Retail Store](http://apple.com/retail) (preferably during the week when it's not too busy) and ask very nicely if they can help you out. If not, I'd go back to Microcenter and tell them they cost you $30.

Answer (score 4):

Apple's policy is that you get an OS upgrade for free as soon as the launch date of the new OS has been officially announced. For Lion, this was [after July 21st](http://www.apple.com/macosx/uptodate/). However, as you discovered yourself:

> Remember your completed order must be entered within 30 days of the date of your purchase of a qualifying computer.

So no, you won't be able to get anything from Apple's [up-to-date program](http://www.apple.com/macosx/uptodate/), which is the only way to get an OS upgrade for free.